# what is function pointers in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

can some one clarify what is function pointers in vb script

Comment: vbscript? while I don't have an answer, I do have a question: why vbscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [GetRef function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10%28VS.85%29.aspx).

From the link:

> GetRef Function
>
> Returns a reference to a procedure
>   that can be bound to an event.
>   ...

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Function GetRefTest()
   Dim Splash
   Splash = "GetRefTest Version 1.0"   & vbCrLf
   Splash = Splash & Chr(169) & " YourCompany 1999 "
   MsgBox Splash
End Function

Set Window.Onload = GetRef("GetRefTest")
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

> A function pointer is a variable that
>   stores the memory address of a block
>   of code that is programmed to fulfill
>   a specific function.

[See this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7107503/Function-Pointers-in-VBScript) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Question vote div starts here-->
                <div id="QuesVoteDiv" class="vote">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageVoteUp" CssClass="voteImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/vote-arrow-up.png"
                                ToolTip="The question is useful and clear(click again to undo)" CommandName="VoteUp" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="VotesLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageVoteDown" CssClass="voteImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/vote-arrow-down.png"
                                ToolTip="The question is unclear or not useful(click again to undo)" CommandName="VoteDown" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="FavouriteQuestionImage" CssClass="VoteFavourite" runat="server"
                                ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/vote-favorite-off.png" ToolTip="This is a favourite question (click again to undo)"
                                OnClick="VoteFavouriteImage_Click"/>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="FavouriteQuestionCountLabel" Text="" runat="server" CssClass="favoritecount-off"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <!-- Question vote div ends here-->
```